# Javascript/html, dynamic divs, individual href's from 2d array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I'm really new to javascript from C# and i'm having a little trouble. I wrote this function to make adding menu's a bit easier on my site. It works well except I can't seem to give my div's an individual url, even though I can give them an individual innerHtml.

I've been stuck trying different things such as divs[i].location.url etc.. but I can't seem to have anything work. My current solution has each div link to /contact.html which I'm a little confused by.

```
function DrawMainMenu() {
    var btns = [
        ["About", "/about.html"],
        ["Portfolio", "/portfolio.html"],
        ["Resume", "/resume.html"],
        ["Contact", "/contact.html"]
    ];
    var numOfBtns = btns.length;
    var divs = new Array(numOfBtns);
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfBtns; i++) {
        divs[i] = document.createElement("div");
        divs[i].className = "menuBtn";
        divs[i].innerHTML = btns[i][0];
        divs[i].style.height = (30 / numOfBtns) + "%";
        divs[i].style.lineHeight = 3.5;
        var link = btns[i][1];
        divs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            location.href = link;
        }, false);
        document.getElementById("buttons").appendChild(divs[i]);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `link` gets overwritten each iteration, so when the event handler it gets `link`, which is the string `'/contact.html'`, since that was the last value given to it.

You can try setting `onclick` attribute to elements, which will store the variable in the attribute `onclick`. Therefore, it will have the old and correct value.

```js
function DrawMainMenu() {
    var btns = [
        ["About", "/about.html"],
        ["Portfolio", "/portfolio.html"],
        ["Resume", "/resume.html"],
        ["Contact", "/contact.html"]
    ];
    var numOfBtns = btns.length;
    var divs = new Array(numOfBtns);
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfBtns; i++) {
        divs[i] = document.createElement("div");
        divs[i].className = "menuBtn";
        divs[i].innerHTML = btns[i][0];
        divs[i].style.height = (30 / numOfBtns) + "%";
        divs[i].style.lineHeight = 3.5;
        var link = btns[i][1];
        divs[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'location.href = "' + link + '"');
        document.getElementById("buttons").appendChild(divs[i]);
    }
}
DrawMainMenu();
```

```html
<div id="buttons"><div>
```

## Updated answer

Here we make use of closures. Using a closure (closing the values of `link`) we bind the value to the scope of the click handler.

```js
function DrawMainMenu() {
  var btns = [
    ["About", "/about.html"],
    ["Portfolio", "/portfolio.html"],
    ["Resume", "/resume.html"],
    ["Contact", "/contact.html"]
  ];
  var numOfBtns = btns.length;
  var divs = new Array(numOfBtns);
  for (var i = 0; i < numOfBtns; i++) {
    (function() {
      divs[i] = document.createElement("div");
      divs[i].className = "menuBtn";
      divs[i].innerHTML = btns[i][0];
      divs[i].style.height = (30 / numOfBtns) + "%";
      divs[i].style.lineHeight = 3.5;
      var link = btns[i][1];
      document.getElementById("buttons").appendChild(divs[i]);
      divs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        location.href = link;
      }, false);
    }());
  }
}
DrawMainMenu();
```

```html
<div id="buttons"><div>
```

Comment: What a great solution! Really cool that you can use 'onclick' in setAttribute(). Thanks for the help, I really appreciate the reply!

Comment: @luna-games actually there is an alternative too. I've added that to my code. You can try that too.